# Node js using express-validation

Tags: node.js, express-validator

I have this file validation:

```
import { check } from "express-validator";

exports.validateAuthor = [
    check('name', 'name is required').not().isEmpty()
]
```

and I used it on:

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import { getItems, getItem, createItem, updateItem, deleteItem } from '../controller/author.controller.js';
import { validateAuthor } from'../middleware/author.validator.js';

const router = Router();

router.route('/')
    .get(    (req,res)  => getItems(req,res) )
    .post(   validateAuthor , (req,res)  => createItem(req,res) )
    .patch(  validateAuthor, (req,res) => updateItem(req,res) )
    .delete( (req,res) => deleteItem(req,res) )

router.route(`/:id`)
    .get(    (req,res)  =>  getItem(req,res) )
    

export default router;
```

so, currently I have this issue:

`SyntaxError: The requested module '../middleware/author.validator.js' does not provide an export named 'validateAuthor'`

why?? I just take the example on [express-validation](https://www.tutsmake.com/validation-in-node-js-express-rest-api/)

Comment: Your export/import use two different standards of modularity

Comment: aouch!!! got you! thanks!